# How to set fragment for each page of ViewPager in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

## Fragment:

```
public class XYZFragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.xyz_fragment,null);
    // all code implementations 

    return v;
}
```

### I have **`lot of fragments`** which I want to bind in **`ViewPager`**

---

## Mockup Image

[image: Fragment Mockup]

## Request

If any solution for this then please share.. 
 Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html)

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: What he gave you was correct, you just need to create a class extending this FragmentStatePagerAdapter, and you will get a function called getFragment(int position) just do a switch/case with your fragments